# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row [0 value for dropdown]

Tags: laravel

I try to enter a value from the column name table 1 to table 2. It appears but the top row is worth 0. It's getting error message.

[image: Error]

**Controller**:

```
public function create()
    {
        $kelas_theresia = Kelas_Theresia::pluck('name')->all();
        return view('kamar_theresia.create',compact('kamar_theresia','kelas_theresia'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'nama' => 'required|unique:kamar_theresia,nama',
            'idkelas' => 'required',
            'ketersediaan' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $kamar_theresia = Kamar_Theresia::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('kamar_theresia.index')
                        ->with('success','Kamar Theresia created successfully.');
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Kelas:</strong>
      {!! Form::select('idkelas', $kelas_theresia,[], array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share you migration file?

Comment: class CreateKamarTheresiaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kamar_theresia', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idkelas');
            $table->enum('ketersediaan', ['Isi', 'Terpesan', 'Kosong']);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('idkelas')->references('id')->on('kelas_theresia');
        });
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` function change the line where you retrieve your resource to include the `id`.

So add this instead:

```
$kelas_theresia = Kelas_Theresia::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

So this will use the correct id for the item and when you store it will be the correct one, because now your value is the name.